# How to create Microsoft Dependency injection for onetime tenant scope creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have multi tenant architecture on database divide by database scheme. on Web API, I want to create an instance of a service that load data from database one time, and then get data from service like a cache instead of access database every time.
The problem is when I did dependency injection there are 3 life time scopes which are

1. Singleton
2. Transient
3. Scope

for Transient and Scope it will create new instance every time request is coming, and Singleton it will create 1 time but it will mix with all tenant

My question is how can I create the instance of service that like Singleton of each tenant with Microsoft Dependency injection?

if it cannot do that are there any options that use instead? one thing I think it may work is create Singleton with key - value and when each tenant access this service it must send tenant id to find only data for that tenant but this service will have all data of all tenant.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how can I create the instance of service that like Singleton of each tenant with Microsoft Dependency injection?

You are looking for a "per tenant lifestyle" in MS.DI, but there isn't. The three basic lifestyles is all you got with MS.DI and there's little way to extend that.

This means you will have to implement the caching internally in your class. There are many ways to do this. You could, for instance, use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where the `TKey` is some identifier for the tenant. The dictionary can be stored in a private field and the class can be made Singleton. Note that you need to take thread safety into consideration when it comes to Singletons.

Here's a quick example:

```cs
public class TenantCacheImpl : IService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, Cache> cache = new();

    // Allows retrieving the current tenant information
    private readonly ITenantContext context;

    public TenantCacheImpl(ITenantContext context) => this.context = context.

    public Cache GetCache()
    {
        lock (this.cache)
        {
            return this.cache[this.context.Tenant.Id];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the singleton `IMemoryCache` and my keys or formatted strings like `$"{tenantId}-Rooms"`. Additionally in memory cache you can define lifetimes of the entries and on update requests for the given resource I simply remove the key, so that at next read request the cache will be refreshed.